# Adding php define list to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big list of PHP defines. I'm using it as a language file. I want to move language definations from that file to MySQL table. Is there some useful function that I could use?

Format in language file:

```
define("TXT_HELLO", "Hello!");
define("TXT_BYE", "Bye!");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [get_defined_constants()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php), which will return you array with all defined constants.

Then, you can walkthrough that array using `foreach` and insert them into your database.

Try:

```
print_r(get_defined_constants(true)); // true means the consts will be categorized
```